# DragManager problem when loading flex app into flash app

Tags: apache-flex, flash, drag-and-drop

I have a flex application which use DragManager.
When I'm loading this application into flash application
and trying to use drag'n'drop functions - I get an error:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>   `at mx.managers::CursorManagerImpl/showCurrentCursor()`
>   `at mx.managers::CursorManagerImpl/setCursor()`
>   `at mx.managers.dragClasses::DragProxy/showFeedback()`
>   `at mx.managers.dragClasses::DragProxy/mouseMoveHandler()`

But, when I simply run a flex application (not loding it into a flash one) everything works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A brief look at the said method `CursorManagerImpl/showCurrentCursor()` shows that it accesses many Flex-specific properties such as `systemManager.stage`, `systemManager.document`, `Application.application` etc. Since you are loading a flex app into a Flash movie, may be some of these flex-specific parameters are not initialized properly.